# Поиск по координатам в MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, geojson

Есть одна коллекция в монго, там лежат документы, каждый из которых содержит array coordinates, например [59.952673, 30.293132]. Для поиска по этим координатам я использую индекс 2dsphere. И ищу с помощью запроса:

```
db.objects.find({coordinates: {$nearSphere: {$geometry: {
                   type: "Point",
                   coordinates: [59.952673, 30.293132]},
                   $maxDistance: 100
               }}}).limit(5)
```

Для указаннх координатов все работает корректно. Например вот результат [поиска в гугл](https://www.google.com/maps?q=59.952673,%2030.293132), это существующие координаты. Но при этом, [также существующие координаты](https://www.google.com/maps?q=64.89633499999999,%20141.724606)
[64.89633499999999, 141.724606] выдают ошибку:

```
db.objects.find({coordinates: {$nearSphere: {$geometry: {
                       type: "Point",
                       coordinates: [64.89633499999999, 141.724606]},
                       $maxDistance: 100
                   }}}).limit(5)
[2022-09-30 15:43:49] Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 64.89633499999999, 141.724606 ] }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 64.8963 lat: 141.725'
```

Что я делаю не так? Почему в одном случае координаты корректны, а в другом они is out of bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В сообщении сказано:

> Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'invalid point in geo near query $geometry argument: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ 64.89633499999999, 141.724606 ] }  longitude/latitude is out of bounds, lng: 64.8963 lat: 141.725'

**Что здесь важно?**

Важен порядок следования параметров `longitude/latitude` (или `долгота/широта`)
и то как он распознал ваши координаты:

```
lng: 64.8963 
lat: 141.725
```

или

```
долгота: 64.8963 
широта: 141.725
```

А как известно координаты, измеряемые в градусах имеют следующий диапазон:

- широта от −90° до +90°
- долгота от −180° до +180°

В Вашем случае широта (которая может находится в диапазоне от -90 до +90) имеет значение 141.725, которые выходят за рамки данного диапазона.

Предположу, что Вы перепутали местами значения широты и долготы из-за неопределенности в порядке следования данных параметров в разных системах отсчета.

Поэтому просто поменяйте порядок указания значений координат в ваших запросах и **перепроверьте, что данные уже занесенные в базу данных имеют корректные координаты** (вполне возможно, что они также указаны в неверном порядке.)

Comment: Всё верно, у меня в БД данные были записаны некорректно - latitude/longitude. И передавал данные в запрос я тоже в таком порядке. Поэтому часть данных искалась корректно, а другая is out of bounds. Спасибо за пояснение!